# is there a way around working with JS and ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp page on my website (using a master page, if that's necessary to mention), and Im using this image gallery that I downloaded that using jquery. The download is just basically a HTML page with a few divs and classes with hyperlinks of images. Nothing fancy. Apart from the bottom of the page that has a bit of javascript.

The problem is that when I run the page, the 'next' button does not work. But when I load the temlate HTML page, it does.

So I googled if Javascript works with ASP.NET, and it turns out it does not. So now I have no idea what to do. Should I change the pages to HTML (which I dont want to do) or is there a way around this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I change the pages to HTML

The pages are already HTML, at least as far as the browser is concerned.

> I googled if Javascript works with ASP.NET, and it turns out it does not.

JavaScript is not supported as a *server side* ASP.NET language (although JScript is supported in Classic ASP).

There is nothing stopping you outputting *client side* JavaScript from ASP.NET or outputting a `<script src...>` element in an HTML document from ASP.NET that loads JS from a static file.

> The problem is that when I run the page, the 'next' button does not work.

Then you need to debug your code. Look for errors in the JS console. Check the source (as received by the browser) to make sure that what ASP.NET is generating matches what you expect. etc.

Comment: Well the .html file works perfect. It has a header with external css links and src for javascripts. I then copy this code and place it into my asp page, get rid of the headers and the body and html tags, (making sure the external links are still in the header of my master page) and it still doesnt work. The only difference between the html page and the asp page is practically the header, which the masterpage has anyway. I really cant see the problem

Comment: Also, I tried adding the javascript to a new JS file, and used a <script src> link to refer to, and it worked, but only on the html page, not my asp

Comment: Since we can't see your code, it is even harder for us to see what the problem is. Look at your browser's debugging tools. Check that the JS is being loaded. Check that you aren't getting 404 errors for your resources. Add break points to the JavaScript. Check that elements it tries to find in the DOM are being found.

Comment: turned out it was my css that was messing it up. Your answer was great, thanks.